# Windows Phone 7 Application + WCF + SSL + Username Authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication, windows-phone-7

I have developed a test service with WCF, which I try to consume from a Windows Phone 7 Application, however when calling a method from the service I get a weird exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://server/Service.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often
>   caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action.

The WCF service uses a custom binding with UserNameOverTransport authentication and SSL. For the authorization I am using an implementation of the UserNamePasswordValidator. If I try to consume the service from a console or silverlight application (cross domain policy is enabled) - it works fine (authorization as well). And the most weird thing is that the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file generated for the WP7 App is **exactly** the same as the config file generated for the silverlight application.

I have no idea what is wrong with my service...

Answer (score 3):

First suggestion: don't assume it's your service at fault. The WM7 SDK is far from bug-free. I suggest writing a conventional WPF, WinForms or Console client to test your service to be sure it's not a WM7 problem.

Comment: Well I tried WPF, WinForms, Console or even ASP.NET Application and they all work fine...

Comment: well then, the only conclusion is that the wm7 sdk is broken, no?

Answer (score 0):

By the date of this question, it seems to me you were testing this in the emulator and the emulator doesn't support HTTPS.